# What's wrong with this code in language C?

Tags: c, file-handling, file-read

I study on an university and I got a task to do, and this needs to read a file in C. I'm very beginner in C and the teacher not so helpful, so I need someone other helps.

What's wrong with this code:

```
void main( )
{
    FILE *fp ;
    char ch ;
    fp = fopen("text.txt","r") ;
    while ( 1 )
    {
        ch = fgetc ( fp ) ;
        if ( ch == EOF )
            break ;
        printf("%c",ch) ;
    }
    fclose (fp ) ;
}
```

I got this code from https://www.javatpoint.com/file-handling-in-c but it's still not working very well. :(

Thank you for the help, and sorry for the bad English. :)

Comment: `char ch;` should be `int ch;`

Comment: Please be a little bit more specific. What is it _supposed to do_, and what is it actually doing for you?

Comment: *Is* there a file called `text.txt` because the coder forgot to check if it opened. The code isn't very good code, is there a better tutorial you can follow? In particular the linked page says "Consider the following example which opens a file in write mode" which is plain **wrong**.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We can't help you with "what's wrong with this code" because it's [not a real question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). You need to explain precisely what is supposed to happen, what does happen instead, and how that is different. You also need to [attempt your own research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Also, consider whether a tutorial for C language on a website called "java t point" might not be the best.

Comment: This is not a very good place to get your C code from. Do not recommend.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please understand that we can't tell you what's wrong with your code if you don't communicate what your code is supposed to do. Please edit your question to include expected behavior and how it differs from what you're actually getting.

Answer (score 0):

Program at least should check if `fp` is not a null pointer, that's the wrong part of this code.

```
fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");

if (!fp) // did we open it?
{
    printf("File is not available \n");
}
else
{
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", ch);
    }
    fclose (fp) ;
}
```

Comment: The URL works for me, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Ah, now I see it.... :)

Comment: The joke is the same if you refer to the title, then you can add emphasis.

Comment: This may not have been the answer OP was looking for, as no question was truly asked